# jQuery - .width() returning 0 on imgs with max-height

Tags: php, jquery, width, dynamically-generated

So I have a horizontally scrolling div and I need to find out how wide that div needs to be based on the dynamically generated list of images inside of it.

I want to use jQuery to find the width of all the images, and set the div's width to that integer.

**Here is my jQuery that isn't working:**

```
<script>

    function findWidth() {

        var totalwidth = 0;
        $('img.you').each(function() {
            totalwidth += $(this).width();
            console.log($(this).css("width"));
        });
        $('#scrollbox').css("width", totalwidth);

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        findWidth();
    });

</script>
```

The CSS applied to each of my images:

```
.you {
    max-height: 215px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    border: 7px solid #f5f5f5;
    margin-left: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgb(70, 70, 70);
}
```

I've tried .width() and .css("width")... nothing.

I've tried $(document).ready() and .load()... nothing.

**Here is my PHP that is displaying all the images in an array that I populate elsewhere:**

```
<?php

    //$myImages is an array of links.
    $index = 0;
    foreach($myImages as $key=>$value) {
        // do stuff
        $index++;

        echo <<<EOF
        <img class="you" src="$value" alt="">
EOF;

    }
?>
```

**The Problem:**

The problem is is keeps logging 0 no matter what image it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `width` set in the CSS, so using `css('width')` probably gets you `auto`, as that is the default CSS value for width, and `width()` gets you 0, as the images are'nt loaded yet and have no width ?

To get the actual with of the images, you'll have to wait until they are loaded, but something like this should work:

```
function findWidth() {
    var totalwidth = 0;
    $('img.you').each(function() {
        totalwidth += $(this).width();
    });
    $('#scrollbox').css("width", totalwidth);
}

$(window).on('load', function() {
    findWidth();
});
```

Comment: @RickBross - Too old jQuery, it's at version 2.0 now!